# Jaccard/binary (dis)similarity calculation to multidimensional scaling analysis

Tags: r, distance-functions, multidimensional-scaling, jaccard-similarity, pcoa

I have n N x n dataset of features (n) and subjects (N) in which I am attempting to cluster into a lower-dimensional space via multi-dimensional scaling.

I'm confused about which MDS setup I need to use for this data: interval, ratio, or ordinal.

I'm feeding the MDS function (smacof::mds) my distance matrix:

mds(data.dst, ndim = 3)

From my readings, the literature claims that since my data is binary, I have to use the ordinal approach.

However, my distance function is based on the jaccard calculation, which transforms the (dis)similarities into an interval vector of distances.

since data.dst are interval distances, would an interval MDS approach work?

Comment: If you understand a little Portuguese, take a look at Chapter 1 of https://datascience.insper.edu.br/

Comment: I unfortunately do not :(

Comment: If you understand a little Spanish, it's quite similar. At least read the code. The answer you're looking for is there in the scoth whisky market example

Comment: I see that instead of an MDS, something similar to the jaccard distance matrix is calculated similarly, then hierarchically clustered in a dendrogram.

My approach is to use MDS on the distances, then use hierarchical clustering to visualize the similarities. I chose this approach as my data is high dimensional, and has more variables (i.e., features) than subjects.

Is there a benefit to skipping the MDS approach altogether? It may be explained in the document, but unfortunately, I do not speak Spanish or Portuguese

Thanks for the response!

Comment: You should consider posting a slice of your data. If you have a well defined distance between your objects, you can do hierarchical clustering directly. In this case, MDS would be useful to visualize your objects in, say, two dimensions. But the hclust can be done without MDS. If all you have is a dissimilarity between your objects (and that's explained in the book), then you would start with MDS, get a low dimensional representation of your objects, compute the euclidean distances in this low dimensional representation and then do you clustering, hierachical, k-means, or whatever.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. From the chapter you provided, and your explanation, this is the approach that is best suited.